# Why after compiling/building my AWS sdk jar is only 3kb?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jboss, pom.xml

I was previously on 1.6.x and mvn clean install builds wit no issues; end up with a 10mb jar and able to run all my code.

Now I want to upgrade to 1.10.x for the new lambda/apig/ddb support, I changed the version from 1.6.x to 1.10.x.

But after I build with mvn clean install, I see the jar is only 3kb, why is that? Has something changed with the way the AWS sdk works? At least from I've seen, one new way is you can be pick specific services rather than the whole sdk.

Edit:

The 3kb jar has the following:

- pom.properties:

  - version=1.10.66
  - groupId=com.amazonaws
  - artifactId=aws-java-sdk
- pom.xml, which lists all the aws sdk services

Answer (score 1):

Have you uncompresssed the jar file and looked up what is in that folder? Based on the information in your question, I guess you have just got your own source files there but not the dependencies. If any, maven dependencies are usually located at `META-INF\maven` in jar. BTW, do you use maven plugins? For example, `maven-jar-plugin` only outputs your source code in jar while `maven-assembly-plugin` also outputs maven dependencies.

Comment: updated op; just contain a pom.xml and pom.properties.

Comment: please update with maven clean install console output too.